# Customize request format in Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I am building a Rails 5 backend API which will receive requests from my Ember app. However I'm having some trouble getting Ember to format the request in a way my Rails server understands.

By default, Rails creates controllers to expect parameters in this format, assuming the model is a, say, `Car`:

```
"car": {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Foo",
  "bar": "Bar",
  ...
}
```

However it looks like Ember is sending requests in this format:

```
"data": [
  {
    id: "1",
    type: "cars",
    attributes: {
      "name: "Foo",
      "bar": "Bar",
      ...
  }
]
```

What can I do to make Ember send request payloads in a way my Rails server will understand? Thank you.

Comment: Rails accepting format is REST format, so application adapter and serializer should extend `RESTAdapter` not `JSONAPIAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried changing my Application adapter (application.js) to a RESTAdapter, but I don't understand how to use the RESTSerializer. Can you help me?

Comment: Your serializer also should extend `DS.RESTSerializer`. If your backend API request response is adhere to REST format then everything will work out of the box...If you are writing the backend then consider JSONAPI format

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, I don't know where to set up a REST Serializer in an Ember application (I'm a little new). But I noticed there is the application adapter under app/adapters/application.js. Would the serializer go under app/serializers/application.js?

Comment: Yes you are right. `ember g serializers application` will create the file but by default it will extend with JSONAPISerializer, you need to modify it to RESTSerializer

Comment: Sorry it was `ember g serializer application`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Rails is accepting REST adapter format, for that to work properly, your adapter should extend `DS.RESTAdapter` and serializer should extend `DS.RESTSerializer`. By default it will comes with `JSONAPIAdapter` and `JSONAPISerializer`.

If you are having control over the back end code, then consider writing json-api format response for that ember will work out of the box.

Reference:
https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RESTAdapter
https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RESTSerializer

https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter
https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14.9/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer